# Automate css browser vendors prefixes in meteor

Tags: css, meteor, vendor-prefix

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to use `autoprefixer` (https://npmjs.org/package/autoprefixer) to automatically process the CSS with meteor.

I'm trying to enable the node package to work with meteor with `meteor-npm` but then I don't really get what to do or if it is at all possible.

Answer (score 5):

My first choice would be to use [stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) (see below), but based on your comments it looks like you are using less. It may be possible to create a [local package](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages) which adds a source handler for all less files. See the [less plugin](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/less/plugin) and the [stylus plugin](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/stylus/plugin).

Alternatively, you could use an external process to compile your files. I use a [Cakefile](https://gist.github.com/dweldon/4644690) to watch my `.jade` files and turn them into `html`. Maybe you could do something similar with autoprefixer.

---

```
$ meteor add stylus
```

The package comes with [nib](http://visionmedia.github.io/nib/) which solves the problem you are asking about. Here's an example:

#### example.styl

```
@import 'nib'

$bluestart = #0076b8
$bluestop = #005a8d

footer
  border-radius: 5px
  background: linear-gradient(top, $bluestart, $bluestop)
```

The compiled css will have all of the border radius and gradient prefixes expanded for you.

Comment: I would actually prefer to use stylus, but I have to keep working with  less at the moment. I read there is a stylus autoprefixer thingy as well, which i haven't tried.

Comment: I'm currently testing Lea Verou's client side Prefix-free. But I would be interested to find out how to make that happen with autoprefixer and meteor.

Comment: I added some more suggestions to my answer.

Comment: ouch ouch ouchydoky !              :)

Comment: but then I would need stylus2less when I have to share my code with the team :)

Answer (score 2):

There are ever more meteor packages available! At the time of writing, there are three less+autoprefixer packages amongst the offerings:

https://atmospherejs.com/?q=autoprefix

Answer (score 2):

You should just use [seba:minifiers-autoprefixer](https://github.com/sebakerckhof/meteor-minifiers-autoprefix) package. For Meteor 1.3+:

```
meteor remove standard-minifier-css
meteor add seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
```

It will autoprefix all CSS processed by Meteor in production. It does not matter where CSS is coming from (SCSS, Stylus, raw, etc.).